# Is there a javascript templating library that uses the same syntax as the one in PlayFramework 1.x?

Tags: javascript, playframework, template-engine, playframework-1.x

I am looking for a javascript templating library that exactly matches the syntax of the Play 1.x templating language, so I can share templates in a client-server environment.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge.

But there is a [Mustache module](https://github.com/murz/play-mustache) for Play 1.x, which allows you to *"define logic-less template snippets that can be used server-side in your Play views as well as client-side in your JavaScript"* according to the modules homepage.

Comment: I'm familiar with a fair number of JavaScript template engines, but Play's template syntax is pretty unique. Mustache may not be as powerful, but it's quite portable. I would suggest looking into this option as well.